# Creating a mixed network. for windows and ubuntu

Tags: networking, windows-7, wireless-access-point

As a Ubuntu newbie (11.10) I have a wired desktop, and a laptop on Ubuntu, and another windows 7 laptop I use for college...

How do I get them to "talk" to one another, for sharing files... sharing printing... and the like...

my Win laptop does not see the Ubuntu machines, even though they connect to the same FIOS Gateway...

Help???

Answer (score 1):

Install samba

- sudo apt-get install samba
- sudo apt-get install samba samba-common
- sudo apt-get install python-glade2
- sudo apt-get install system-config-samba

do a google search on [ubuntu to windows share + samba](http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&output=search&q=ubuntu%20to%20windows%20share%20%2b%20samba&oq=ubuntu%20to%20windows%20share%20%2b%20samba&fp=976397350e8ab85)

Answer (score 1):

You sould look at samba sharing for Ubuntu. It's recognized by Windows.

On the windows side, you've just to share a folder, Ubuntu can access to it. type this in file explorer of ubuntu (Nautilus) (To type this, hit CTRL+L) : 
`smb://HostIP/SharePath` and it'll show the content of the share.

You'll have to install samba : `sudo apt-get install samba` to share.

To read a share, it's already included in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but, I don't think you can do it on campus since they have their own private broadcast.

You can try pogoplug (cloud, shared printer. there's also a desktop software for it, which allows you to view the file from "mycomputer"), i-twin USB drive (allows you to share file from one computer to another, it use the memory from your harddrive, not usb).